# How to solve this recurrence relation? (number of multiplications to calculate $x^n$)

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find the number of multiplications to calculate $x^n$.
I have arrived at this:

$$M(n) = \begin{cases}
 - 1 + M\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) & \text{if $n$ even}\\
 - 2 + M\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) & \text{if $n$ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

with initial conditions $M(1) = 0$ and $M(2) = 1$.

so how do I solve this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is an easy answer in terms of the binary representation of $n$. I am sure you can work it out given this hint.

Answer (score 2):

Sequence A014701 in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A014701.

Answer (score 0):

But that is not always the best. Knuth has a very detailed (as always) discussion of this problem. iirc, 15 is the first value at which your method is not the best.